# How to absolutely position the last item separately in Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to just set the left value of a absolutely positioned div different from other divs. I tried the last: property of tailwind, but its not working.

Here's my code thet I tried

```
absolute z-10 -ml-4 transform px-2 w-screen max-w-md sm:px-0 lg:ml-0 -left-5 last:left-20"
```

I added these classes and only want the last mapped div to have different position

Sample code:

```
<div class='relative w-full h-72'>
{items.map((each, i ) => {
    return (
    <div key={i} class='absolute top-0 left-0 last:left-10'>{each}</div
    )
})}
</div>
```

and the last div that is mapped should have different left value

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to v2.1 and JIT mode, you need to explicitly enable the `last-child` variant in your `tailwind.config.js`, as it's not enabled for any core plugins.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ...
    variants: {
        extend: {
            inset: ['last']
        }
    }
}
```

Playground demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Wt6reZBsRY

---

From v2.1, when using [Just-in-Time mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) no extra configuration is required as all styles are generated on-demand.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    // ...
}
```